# TypeError: expected string or buffer in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

TypeError: expected string or buffer

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://kteq.in/services")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
   result = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", link.get('href'))
   print result
   print "____________________________________________________"
```

When I run the above code,it shows TypeError in the 7th line. Can't rectify the error.  Please suggest me.

Comment: `print link.get('href')`, you will know the error and you can try passing parser as well in `beautiful soup` as `BeautifulSoup(html_page,html.parser)`

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing the href values.

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    result = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", link.get('href'))
```

You'll see there is a `None` value that comes up after extracting few links.

You can fix this by giving a if condition inside the loop

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    if link.get('href')==None:
        continue
    result = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thank You so much. The code you've suggested is useful.

Comment: Thank You so much for your suggestion. I got the output.